# matlab how to extract 2D image data from warp() function?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, coordinates

This is the code to test pol2cart() and cart2pol:

```
clear all
close all
clc

% data = imread('D:\Projects\CarPool\TestData\test_img1.bmp');
data = phantom(128);
img = sum(data, 3);
[M, N] = size(img);

xvec = linspace(-N/2, N/2);

% convert pixel coordinates from cartesian to polar

[x, y] = meshgrid(xvec,xvec);
[theta, rho] = cart2pol(x, y);

[xx, yy] = pol2cart(theta, rho);

%# show pixel locations (subsample to get less dense points)
xdisp = x(1:8:end,1:4:end);
ydisp = y(1:8:end,1:4:end);
tdisp = theta(1:8:end,1:4:end);
rdisp = rho(1:8:end,1:4:end);
xxdisp = xx(1:8:end,1:4:end);
yydisp = yy(1:8:end,1:4:end);

% h = warp(xx, yy, zeros(size(xx)), img);
% imgWarp = get(h, 'FaceColor');imgWapr = sum(imgWarp,3);
% imgWarp = (imgWarp - min(imgWarp(:)))/max(imgWarp(:));
% img = (img - min(img(:)))/max(img(:));
% diffImg = img - imgWarp;

figure; clf

subplot(241)
scatter(xdisp(:),ydisp(:),3,'filled', 'red'), axis ij image
title('cartesian coordinates'); xlabel('x'); ylabel('y');
subplot(242)
scatter(tdisp(:),rdisp(:),3,'filled'), axis ij square tight, 
title('cartesian to polar coordinates'); xlabel('\theta'); ylabel('\rho');
subplot(243)
scatter(xxdisp(:),yydisp(:),3,'filled'), axis ij square tight, 
title('cartesian to polar coordinates'); xlabel('x'); ylabel('y');
subplot(244)
scatter(xdisp(:),ydisp(:),3,'filled', 'red'), axis ij image; hold on
scatter(xxdisp(:),yydisp(:),3,'filled', 'blue'), axis ij square tight, 
legend('orginal cartesian coordinates', 'coordinates from polar to cartesian');
title('cartesian to polar coordinates'); xlabel('x'); ylabel('y');

%# show images

subplot(245), imshow(img), axis on
title('cartesian'); xlabel('x'); ylabel('y');
subplot(246), warp(theta, rho, zeros(size(theta)), img)
title('cartesian to polar'); xlabel('\theta'); ylabel('\rho');
view(2), axis square
subplot(247), warp(xx, yy, zeros(size(xx)), img)
title('polar to cartesian'); xlabel('x'); ylabel('y');
view(2), axis image

subplot(248)

imagesc(diffImg); colormap(gray); colorbar;
title('difference'); xlabel('x'); ylabel('y');
view(2), axis image
```

Here is my results. Basically the first image is the original, the second is cart2pol, the third is pol2cart.

[image]

My questions is: How do I see the difference between the first and third images? (If you look at my script, the data of the first image is `img`, but I have no idea how to find such a data for the third image? The third image is simply using `warp()` function to do the display.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `warp(x,y,z,img)` first parses your input by calling the function `[x,y,z,cdata,cdatamapping,clim,map,likeimage] = parse_inputs(varargin{:});` in which `im2double` is applied to your `img` in order to get `cdata`. After that,

```
surface(x,y,z,cdata,'EdgeColor','none','FaceColor','texturemap', ...
        'CDataMapping',cdatamapping);
```

is called to display your image.

So your three figures all show `img` with your given coordinates, and your figure 1 and 3 should be the same.

You can `type warp` for more details of the function.

Comment: So, if an image in matlab is cart2pol() first to get imgPol, then the imgPol is processed with pol2cart() to get imgCart, then imgCart is the same as img? That does not sound make sense.....

Comment: cart2pol applied to the coordinates but not img. The output of cart2pol are provided to surface function just to tell it how to display img.

Comment: so it it the surface function that does all the re-sampling, re-gridding?

Comment: I'm not sure how surface function works because it is a built-in function. I guess some interpolations is used in the function(interp2(x,y,img,x1,x2)), so x,y is the output of your cart2pol, and x1,x2 are the interpolations among x and y